# How to make this awk command more simple

Tags: linux, awk, cut, gawk

Is there a way to make this command more simple (ie. not using *awk* twice):

```
awk '/cpu MHz/ {print $4}' < /proc/cpuinfo | awk -F'.' 'NR==1 {print $1}'
```

?

Also, is there a way to avoid using *cut* command here:

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}' | cut -f1 -d '/'
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: This should really be two questions in my opinion. Also, I would suggest adding the sample input and expected output to the question(s). For example, the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo/`, the output of `ip addr show dev eth0` and which parts you are trying to extract.

Comment: Always helpful to include a sample of your input and your desired output.

Comment: `awk '/cpu MHz/ { print int($4) }' /proc/cpuinfo`? `ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '/inet / { print gensub("/.*", "", "", $2) }'`?

Comment: @twalberg Instead of using `int()` function you can just add `0` to it. `awk '/cpu MHz/ { print $4+0 }' /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: @jaypal I suspect that's version dependent. My version of `awk` gives "1.5" when I `echo 1.5 | awk '{print $0+0}'`... Or it's a result of the fact that the numbers after the decimal are all zeros. Obviously not true in the general case, though...

Comment: @twalberg You are correct. It is probably due to trailing `0`. A positive number does show up. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech for the link. Using the unary plus operator is still not dropping the numbers after `.` if they are not `0`.

Comment: @jaypal I removed the comment/link because I didn't realise that `int` was being used for rounding as well as numeric conversion

Comment: @TomFenech I kind of figured. `:)` but wanted to thank for the link anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one is like this:

```
awk '/cpu MHz/ {print $4}' < /proc/cpuinfo | awk -F'.' 'NR==1 {print $1}'
```

Considering you have a string like this:

```
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cpu MHz         : 800.000
cpu MHz         : 800.000
```

And you want the integer part of the number just for first line, you can do:

```
$ awk -F"[ .]" '/cpu MHz/ {print $(NF-1); exit}' /proc/cpuinfo
800
```

That is, to match the line, print the penultimate field and then exit to avoid extra processing.

As per comments, you also want to get the 2nd matching line in a different command. For this, you can do:

```
awk -F"[ .]" '/cpu MHz/ {if (f) {print $(NF-1); exit}; f=1}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

What it does is to use a flag. On the first match, the flag is activated, so on next one it prints the value and exits.

---

Second one is like this:

```
ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}' | cut -f1 -d '/'
```

What you can do is to split the second field in slices based on `/` and print the first one:

```
$ ip addr show dev eth0 | awk '$1=="inet" {split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]}'
192.168.123.123
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I make another for the second line, too?

I have this in my _cpuinfo_:

    cpu MHz         : 1000.000
    cpu MHz         : 1000.000

Comment: @user3628725 see my update. Also, if my solution does not match your requirements, please update with your current sample input so I can guess what is not working.

Comment: thanks, the thingy with _ip addr show_ works. Regarding the first question, I need to extract both the first and the second lines (in two separate commands). How can I adapt the command you suggested to match the second line?

Comment: @user3628725 I just updated with a version to print the matching of the second line.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to show IP address on your interface, then this is not a good option:

```
ip addr show dev eth0
```

What if interface has another name, or you have more than one interface and `eth1` is the one connected to internet?

Us this instead:

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '/8.8.8.8/ {print $NF}'
192.168.0.33
```

To store it in an variable:

```
IP=$(ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '/8.8.8.8/ {print $NF}')
```

It uses `ip route` command to see how to get to an public IP, so will work correct for any name of interface.

Comment: Thank you, @Jotne, it doesn't matter to me (I only have one interface), but I'll use it, it's simpler.

Comment: @daimonion You are welcome. If you move your server to a `VPS` farm, the single if may be named some like: `venet0`

Comment: +1; is it advisable to repeat the input IP address in the `awk` program for matching, or would `ip route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '{print $NF; exit}'` work too?

Comment: @mklement0 In fact this works too: `ip route get 1 | awk '{print $NF;exit}'`

Comment: Thanks, interesting; this works, because `1` is interpreted as `1.0.0.0`, which is apparently a valid address.

Comment: @mklement0 `ping 1` is the same as `0.0.0.1`.  And since its not in the private range `10.x 172.16-32.x 192.168.x` it will work fine.

Comment: If you look at the output from `ip route get 1`, you'll see that it resolves to `1.0.0.0` (apparently, `ping` and `ip route` work differently); conversely, if you try `ip route get 0.0.0.1`, you'll get an _error_ stating `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`. Also, it appears to work fine with addresses in the private ranges, too: `for a in 10.0.0.1 172.16.0.1 192.168.0.1; do ip route get $a | awk '{print $NF;exit}'; done`

Comment: @mklement0 I may be at sleep..  Best way here is to use a know working ip, like `8.8.8.8`.  I too see that some program handles the IP `1` differently.  In windows its `0.0.0.1`